# Can I insert a react component to tinymce editor

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5, tinymce-6

Can I insert a react component to tinymce editor?

I need to custom a toolbar and after user click it, I need to insert a react component to tinymce editor, can I implement it?

Can I insert a react component to tinymce editor?

I need to custom a toolbar and after user click it, I need to insert a react component to tinymce editor, can I implement it?

Answer (score 1):

To start we need to understand that for the plugins to work, we need to be able to inject the project context. In my case, I was using `react-intl`, `Material-UI`, `Axios`, `react-query`, and you might have others, so I created a component for that:

```
import { MuiPickersUtilsProvider } from "@material-ui/pickers";
import AxiosInterceptors from "AxiosInterceptors";
import { GlobalDataProvider } from "hooks/globalData";
import { queryClient } from "index";
import en from "intl/en";
import React from "react";
import { DndProvider } from "react-dnd";
import { HTML5Backend } from "react-dnd-html5-backend";
import { IntlProvider } from "react-intl";
import { QueryClientProvider } from "react-query";
import DateFnsUtils from "@date-io/date-fns";

type AppDependenciesProviderProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
};

export const AppDependenciesProvider = ({
  children,
}: AppDependenciesProviderProps) => {
  const onIntlError = (err: any) => {
    console.log(err);
  };

  return (
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
      <AxiosInterceptors />
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
        <IntlProvider locale="en" messages={en} onError={onIntlError}>
          <GlobalDataProvider>
            <DndProvider backend={HTML5Backend}>{children}</DndProvider>
          </GlobalDataProvider>
        </IntlProvider>
      </QueryClientProvider>
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  );
};
```

This component is called in my `App.tsx` as well in my plugin.

Then, when you call the editor, let's suppose that you need to create a custom component called **medialibrary** (which in my case) it was used to insert images from a custom company blob and to insert images in the editor. I have created a `RichTextEditor` component to call it simpler from the outside.

```
import {
  withStyles,
} from "@material-ui/core";
import { Editor, IAllProps } from "@tinymce/tinymce-react";
import clsx from "clsx";
import RegisterPlugins from "components/TinyMCEPlugins/Plugins/RegisterPlugins";
import { useCallback, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { FieldInputProps, FieldMetaState } from "react-final-form";
import { useIntl } from "react-intl";
import "tinymce/icons/default";
import "tinymce/plugins/code";
import "tinymce/plugins/image";
import "tinymce/plugins/imagetools";
import "tinymce/plugins/link";
import "tinymce/plugins/lists";
import "tinymce/plugins/paste";
import "tinymce/plugins/table";
import "tinymce/plugins/template";
import "tinymce/plugins/textcolor";
import "tinymce/skins/content/default/content.min.css";
import "tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/content.min.css";
import "tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/skin.min.css";
import "tinymce/themes/silver";
import "tinymce/tinymce";
import { Editor as TinyMCEEditor } from "tinymce/tinymce";

type RichTextEditorProps = {  
  setupEditor?: (e: TinyMCEEditor) => void;
} & Partial<IAllProps>;

const RichTextEditor = ({  
  setupEditor,
  init = {},
  ...rest
}: RichTextEditorProps) => {
  
  const [value, setValue] = useState(input.value);  
  const intl = useIntl();
  
  const setup = useCallback((editor: TinyMCEEditor) => {  
    RegisterPlugins({ editor, intl, ...rest });
    setupEditor && setupEditor(editor);
  }, []);  

  return (
    <FormControl
      fullWidth
      error={meta.error && meta.submitFailed}
      focused={focused}
    >
      <InputLabel shrink={forceLabelShrink || value !== "" ? true : undefined}>
        {label !== undefined ? label : ""}
      </InputLabel>
      <div>
        <Editor
          value={value}
          onEditorChange={onEditorChange}
          onSelectionChange={() => false}
          onBlur={onBlur}
          onFocus={onFocus}
          init={{
            branding: false,
            skin: "outside",
            content_css: false,
            height: 200,
            menubar: false,
            plugins: [
              "medialibrary",
              "paste",
              "lists",
              "image",
              "code",
              "imagetools",
              "link",
              "template",
              "table",
            ],
            statusbar: false,
            toolbar:
              "styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | outdent indent | numlist bullist",
            table_toolbar: false,
            setup,
            ...init,
          }}
          {...rest}
        />
      </div>
      {meta.error && meta.submitFailed && (
        <FormHelperText>{meta.error}</FormHelperText>
      )}
    </FormControl>
  );
};

export default withStyles(styles)(RichTextEditor);
```

Now, we need to declare the component `RegisterPlugins` which allow us to declare all our React custom plugins:

```
import MediaLibraryPlugin from "components/TinyMCEPlugins/Plugins/MediaLibraryPlugin";
import { IntlShape } from "react-intl";
import { Editor } from "tinymce";

export type PluginRegistrationProps = {
  editor: Editor;
  intl?: IntlShape; /*in my case, I send the intl from the caller, but you can avoid this*/
};

const RegisterPlugins = ({ ...props }: PluginRegistrationProps) => {
  /*Declare all your plugins here */
  MediaLibraryPlugin({ ...props }); /*this is my custom component*/
};

export default RegisterPlugins;
```

At this point, we need to focus on our custom Plugin, which I recomend to divide in two steps: One for declaring the dialog wrapper and another for declaring what the component does:

```
import { Dialog, DialogContent } from "@material-ui/core";
import { AppDependenciesProvider } from "components/App/AppDependenciesProvider";
import { PluginRegistrationProps } from "components/TinyMCEPlugins/Plugins/RegisterPlugins";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { MediaLibraryPluginView } from "./MediaLibraryPluginView";

const MediaLibraryPlugin = ({
  editor,
  intl,
  ...rest
}: PluginRegistrationProps) => {
  editor.ui.registry.addButton("medialibrary"/*name of the plugin*/, {
    text: "Media Library",
    icon: "gallery", /*You can pick your custom icon*/
    onAction: function () {
      const dialogContainer = document.createElement("div");
      document.body.appendChild(dialogContainer);

      const closeDialog = () => {
        ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(dialogContainer);
        dialogContainer.remove();
      };

      const dialog = (
        <Dialog fullWidth maxWidth={"lg"} open onClose={closeDialog}>
          <DialogContent>
            <AppDependenciesProvider> /*Here we inject the app context as explained in the first step*/
              <MediaLibraryPluginView onClose={closeDialog} editor={editor} />
            </AppDependenciesProvider>
          </DialogContent>
        </Dialog>
      );

      ReactDOM.render(dialog, dialogContainer);
    },
  });
};

export default MediaLibraryPlugin;
```

Finally, we can focus on our React code:

```
import useBoolean from "hooks/useBoolean";
import MediaLibraryItemCreateForm from "pages/MediaLibraryPage/MediaLibraryItemCreateForm";
import { MediaLibraryItemsListView } from "pages/MediaLibraryPage/MediaLibraryItemsListView";
import { IMediaLibraryItem } from "services/KnowfullyAdminClient";
import { TinyMCEPluginBase } from "types/common-types";
import { FileFormat } from "utils/mediaUtils";

export const MediaLibraryPluginView = ({
  editor,
  onClose,
}: TinyMCEPluginBase) => {

  /*This component is absolutely custom. As you can see you can use hooks and whatever dependencies you need to make it work. In my case, this component inserts images coming from a custom source. Demo can be seen below*/
  const [onCreate, setOnCreate] = useBoolean(false);

  const onClickCreateMediaLibraryItem = () => {
    setOnCreate.setTrue();
  };

  const onClickMediaLibraryItem = (mediaLibraryItem: IMediaLibraryItem) => {
    editor.insertContent(
      `<img src="${mediaLibraryItem.fileUrl}" width="${mediaLibraryItem.width}" height="${mediaLibraryItem.height}"/>`
    );

    onClose();
  };

  return !onCreate ? (
    <MediaLibraryItemsListView
      onClickCreateMediaLibraryItem={onClickCreateMediaLibraryItem}
      onClickMediaLibraryItem={onClickMediaLibraryItem}
      options={[FileFormat.IMAGE]}
      contentType={FileFormat.IMAGE}
    />
  ) : (
    <MediaLibraryItemCreateForm onRedirectBack={() => setOnCreate.setFalse()} />
  );
};
```

Here you have the result:

[image: Demo]